# Global Flash Player volume? Override volume of child soundTransforms?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to set a volume level 'above' an object's soundTransform setting in a way that would cause the Sound or Video object to report a volume that is different than what's coming through the speakers?  (Within of the Flash Player, that is—no points for muting the computer.)

Example:

Top Movie: Somehow volume is set to .2
Child Movie: Has sound object with volume set to .8

User hears volume level of .2, but child movie reports it's volume is .8.

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the `SoundMixer.soundTransform` property: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html.

This is essentially the global volume for all sounds in your Flash app. Reducing this will reduce the actual volume that you hear for all sounds - but their `soundtransform.volume` property will be unchanged.